# How can I create a list that is created using the indexes and items of two other lists?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. One is made up of positions from a sentence and the other is made up of words that make up the sentence. I want to recreate the variable sentence using poslist and wordlist.

```
recreate = []
sentence = "This and that, and this and this."
poslist = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5]
wordlist = ['This', 'and', 'that', 'this', 'this.']
```

I wanted to use a for loop to go through poslist and if the item in poslist was equal to the position of a word in wordlist it would append it to a new list, recreating the original list. My first try was:

```
for index in poslist:
    recreate.append(wordlist[index])
print (recreate)
```

I had to make the lists strings to write the lists into a text file. When I tried splitting them again and using the code shown above it does not work. It said that the indexes needed to be slices or integers or slices not in a list. I would like a solution to this problem. Thank you.

The list of words is gotten using:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence >>") #asking the user for an input
sentence_lower = sentence.lower() #making the sentence lower case
wordlist = [] #creating a empty list
sentencelist = sentence.split() #making the sentence into a list

for word in sentencelist: #for loop iterating over the sentence as a list
    if word not in wordlist: 
        wordlist.append(word)

txtfile = open ("part1.txt", "wt")
for word in wordlist:
    txtfile.write(word +"\n")
txtfile.close()

txtfile = open ("part1.txt", "rt")
for item in txtfile:
    print (item)
txtfile.close()
print (wordlist)
```

And the positions are gotten using:

```
poslist = []

textfile = open ("part2.txt", "wt")
for word in sentencelist:
    poslist.append([position + 1 for position, i in enumerate(wordlist) if i == word])

print (poslist)
str1 = " ".join(str(x) for x in poslist)

textfile = open ("part2.txt", "wt")
textfile.write (str1)
textfile.close()
```

Comment: that went above my head. can you re frame?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. I have the two lists. Basically I want to recreate the variable sentence using the list of positions and words that make up the sentence.

Comment: @R.McEvoy Your code works, you just have to substract 1 from the index, because lists are 0-indexed.

Comment: @L3viathan I have tried to do that. When I run the code I am using an input and also the lists have previously been written into text files. The error is, 'list indices must be integers or slices, not lists.'

Comment: @R.McEvoy Assuming my answer doesn't work for you: Can you also show us that part of the code?

Comment: @R.McEvoy please show your complete code

Comment: @JulienSpronck The code is now provided.

Comment: @R.McEvoy ... the code is not complete. what is sentenceList ... also why do you open twice your file for writing? It looks like `poslist` is a list of lists from the provided code. what is the result of `print (poslist)`?

Comment: @JulienSpronck The full code is now provided. I am opening two files for writing. I am writing poslist to one and wordlist to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code can be simplified to:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence >>") #asking the user for an input
sentence_lower = sentence.lower() #making the sentence lower case
wordlist = [] #creating a empty list
sentencelist = sentence.split() #making the sentence into a list

with open ("part1.txt", "wt") as txtfile:
    for word in sentencelist: #for loop iterating over the sentence as a list
        if word not in wordlist: 
            wordlist.append(word)
            txtfile.write(word +"\n")

poslist = [wordlist.index(word) for word in sentencelist]
print (poslist)

str1 = " ".join(str(x) for x in poslist)
with open ("part2.txt", "wt") as textfile:
    textfile.write (str1)
```

In your original code, `poslist` was a list of lists instead of a list of integers.

Then, if you want to reconstruct your sentence from poslist (which is now a list of int and not a list of lists as in the code you provided) and wordlist, you can do the following:

```
sentence = ' '.join(wordlist[pos] for pos in poslist)
```

Comment: @R.McEvoy ... i think this answer should work for you. I made some changes to your original code for this to work.

Comment: Finally a solution that works. Thank you for explaining where I went wrong. I am very grateful.

Comment: @R.McEvoy you're welcome :-) feel free to show your gratitude by upvoting my answer and/or accepting it :-)

Comment: @R.McEvoy also note that you had added 1 to all your positions in your original poslist, I removed that part.

Answer (score 1):

Lists are 0-indexed (the first item has the index 0, the second the index 1, ...), so you have to substract 1 from the indexes if you want to use "human" indexes in the `poslist`:

```
for index in poslist:
    recreate.append(wordlist[index-1])
print (recreate)
```

Afterwards, you can glue them together again and write them to a file:

```
with open("thefile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("".join(recreate))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using a generator expression and the string `join` method:

```
sentence = ' '.join(wordlist[pos-1] for pos in poslist if pos if pos <= len(wordlist))
# 'This and that, and this and this.'
```

Comment: gives the error, 'unorderable types: list() <= int()

Comment: @R.McEvoy I think that `poslist` and `wordlist` are not exactly what you said they were, please show us the code you used to get them

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for this.

```
from operator import itemgetter

poslist = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]
wordlist = ['This', 'and', 'that', 'this', 'this.']

print(' '.join(itemgetter(*poslist)(wordlist)))
```

Note that I had to subtract one from all of the items in `poslist`, as Python is a zero-indexed language. If you need to programmatically change `poslist`, you could do `poslist = (n - 1 for n in poslist)` right after you declare it.